# Unable to access dotenv-webpack variables after build

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-builder, dotenv

I am trying to notarize my Electron + Webpack + React + Typescript application. I use electron-builder to build my app. When I run my application locally I can access my process.env variables but when i try to actually run the notarize script(after build) the process variables are undefined. What am i doing wrong?

I have the following code in my webpack.config.mjs file:

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import CopyPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import TsconfigPathsPlugin from 'tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import { merge } from 'webpack-merge';
// import dotenv from 'dotenv';
// dotenv.config();

import Dotenv from 'dotenv-webpack';

/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
/* eslint-enable */

const isEnvProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const isEnvDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

const commonConfig = {
  devtool: isEnvDevelopment ? 'eval-cheap-module-source-map' : false,
  mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
  output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist') },
  node: { __dirname: false, __filename: false },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^\S+\/\S+\.js$/, (resource) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      resource.request = resource.request.replace(/\.js$/, '');
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    plugins: [
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        configFile: './tsconfig.json',
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      }),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|ico|icns)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.wav$|\.mp3$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};

const mainConfig = merge(commonConfig, {
  entry: './src/main/main.ts',
  target: 'electron-main',
  output: { filename: 'main.bundle.js' },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: 'package.json',
          to: 'package.json',
          transform: (content, _path) => {
            const jsonContent = JSON.parse(content);
            const electronVersion = jsonContent.devDependencies.electron;

            delete jsonContent.devDependencies;
            delete jsonContent.optionalDependencies;
            delete jsonContent.scripts;
            delete jsonContent.build;

            jsonContent.main = './main.bundle.js';
            jsonContent.scripts = { start: 'electron ./main.bundle.js' };
            jsonContent.devDependencies = { electron: electronVersion };

            return JSON.stringify(jsonContent, undefined, 2);
          },
        },
        { from: '../ableton-js/midi-script', to: './dist/' },
      ],
    }),
    new Dotenv({
     
    }),
  ],
});

const preloadConfig = merge(commonConfig, {
  entry: './src/preload/preload.ts',
  target: 'electron-preload',
  output: { filename: 'preload.bundle.js' },
});

const rendererConfig = merge(commonConfig, {
  entry: './src/renderer/renderer.tsx',
  target: 'electron-renderer',
  output: { filename: 'renderer.bundle.js' },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/index.html'),
    }),
  ],
});

export default [mainConfig, preloadConfig, rendererConfig];
"
```

In my package.json I have

```
"build": {
    "afterSign": "./notarize.js",
}
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
}
```

and notarize.js looks like

```
const notarize = require('@electron/notarize');

exports.default = async function notarizing(context) {
  const { electronPlatformName, appOutDir } = context;
  if (electronPlatformName !== 'darwin') {
    return;
  }

  const appName = context.packager.appInfo.productFilename;
  console.log('notarizing', process.env.REACT_APP_APPLEID);

  return await notarize.notarize({
    appBundleId: 'com.yourcompany.yourAppId',
    appPath: `${appOutDir}/${appName}.app`,
    appleId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPLEID,
    appleIdPassword: process.env.APPLEIDPASS,
  });
};
```

All according to https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack.